# Move between variables using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to move quickly from one place in code to another where variable is used? For example I have variable `String strResponse` and it used in several places in code. I want to get from one place where variable used to another quickly using keyboard shortcuts. Is it possible?

VS has "Find all references" option but that's not what I am looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has something like this out of the box: [Highlighted references](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/21/searching-and-navigating-code-in-vs-2010-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). But since you're using Visual Studio 2008 you're out of luck when it boils down to default stuff. However you can install [Resharper which has something similar](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf): <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

### Use bookmarks

Bookmark all variable occurrence then use following shortcut keys to navigate between bookmarks

- Select variable
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> & select "Bookmark All"
- Then use
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> - previous bookmark
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - next bookmark